# filter with Eloquent

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I have 2 tables: tests, questions and I want to show the activated questions of a test:

```
$test = Test::whereHas('questions', function(Builder $query){
            $query->where('activated','=','1');
        })->find($id);
```

but I get the questions; activated and deactivated.

I thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are fetching all tests, that has activated questions.

But when getting the resulting `$test`, you are probably fetching **all** questions with the relation $test->questions.

If you want to fetch only activated questions, you can do the following on the $test object:

```
$test = Test::whereHas('questions', function(Builder $query){
            $query->where('activated','=','1');
        })->find($id);

$questions = $test->questions()->where('activated', '1')->get();
```

With the activated questions eager loaded:

```
$test = Test::whereHas('questions', function(Builder $query){
            $query->where('activated','=','1');
        })->with(['questions' => function ($query) {
    $query->where('activated', '1');
}])->find($id);

// Will only give you the activated questions
var_dump($test->questions);
```

Or you can define a custom relationship in the Test-model, that does the filtering for you.

Comment: I thank you for your answer but I look for a result where I can have one payload. For instance: 
test { "name": "a", "questions": [{id:"1", "activated": 1},{id:"2", "activated": 1}]}

Comment: added another example - but can see @gbalduzzi added the same 4 minutes ago

Comment: you can reuse the closure  `whereHas('questions', $f = function (...) {...})->with(['questions' => $f])` btw

Answer (score 1):

When you use `whereHas`, you are telling eloquent to only select the test with at least one activated question. But you are not telling it to only keep the activated question: you can achieve that using [constrained eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads):

```
$test = Test::with(['questions' => function(Builder $query){
            $query->where('activated','=','1');
        }])->find($id);
```

Comment: Unfortunately I got an error
App\Http\Controllers\API\{closure}() must be an instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder, instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany given

Comment: Just remove `Builder`